# dynamically reference header variables c++

Tags: c++, variables, header-files

I know that C++ cannot create variables at runtime. Everything has to be declared when it is compiled.

My question is, if I have, let's say, 10 included header files with simple variable names, can I reference them dynamically, by the header file name or something like that.

For example, if I had two header files, one called "myVars1.h" with variable "myVars1name" and another called "myVars2.h" with a variable "myVars2name" could I do something like

```
int fileNum = 1;
string name = ["myVars" + fileNum + "name]; //i wish this worked...
```

Is this along the same lines as creating variables at runtime (and therefore illegal)?

Thanks

Comment: To start with, don't *define* variables in header files, or you risk having "multiple definition" linker errors.

Comment: As for your problem, how about a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html) as data? Or just learn to use the [C++ standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Hm. Do you know arrays?

Comment: to clarify my question: I am given the header files and don't have the option to change them. I'm just trying to find a dynamic way to deal with them

Comment: If you get header files that you can't modify, then no there is no such way.

Comment: You can write a script or program that "parses" the header files (rudimentary, maybe you only need the file name) and to generates source code that accesses these variables.

Comment: @DyP Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: If you have 50 or more header files with variables and don't want to write code accessing them (maybe because the number of header files, names of these files, and/or variables names change or the number of variables is large), then you could write some program / script to *generate* this code for you. If you need to access these variables based on run-time information (e.g. user input), then you could generate code that stores the variables in an `unordered_map`, as suggested by Joachim Pileborg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these variables are declared in header files, and defined somewhere else as global variables, you may get what you want by using dlsym(). Basically C/C++ cannot define variables at runtime, but it can load them at run time.

Precondition: these variables must be built into shared library, e.g. mylib.so

```
....
int fileNum = 1;
string name = ["myVars" + fileNum + "name]; //i wish this worked...

void *handle = dlopen("$PATH/mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
void *varPtr = dlsym(handle, name);  // Your wish comes true here...
//cast varPtr to its target type.
....
```

Comment: Cool! That's exactly what I need. Since I know the file names beforehand, I can create the .so

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. Is is possible to dynamically reference namespaces? Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I don't have much power over the header files

Comment: Do you know the number of file you want to access at compile time?

Comment: Not yet, but it could be up to 50